# Подскажите как сделать отображение пунктов меню по разрешению

Tags: java, android, firebase, firestore

```
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new StatisticFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.statistic);
        }

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
        FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        database.collection("users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                            String name = documentSnapshot.getString("name");
                            String userID = documentSnapshot.getString("UserID");
                            UserNameView.setText(name);
                            UserIDView.setText("UserID: " + userID);
                        }
                    }
                });
        if (itemId == R.id.statistic) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new StatisticFragment()).commit();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.time) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TimeFragment()).commit();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.delivery) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new DeliveryFragment()).commit();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }else if (itemId == R.id.odo) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new OdometrFragment()).commit();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }else if (itemId == R.id.information) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new InfoFragment()).commit();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }else if (itemId == R.id.setting) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingFragment()).commit();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }else if (itemId == R.id.taxi) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TaxiFragment()).commit();
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
        else if (itemId == R.id.logout) {
            firebaseAuth.signOut();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn = "navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/statistic"
            android:title="Statistic"
            android:icon="@drawable/stats_drawable"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:title="Hour"
            android:icon="@drawable/time_drawable"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/delivery"
            android:title="Delivery"
            android:icon="@drawable/delivery_drawable"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/odo"
            android:title="Odo"
            android:icon="@drawable/odo_drawable"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/taxi"
            android:title="Taxi"
            android:icon="@drawable/taxi_drawable"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/information"
            android:title="Info"
            android:icon="@drawable/info_drawable"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:title="Setting"
            android:icon="@drawable/setting_drawable"/>

    </group>
    <item android:title=""/>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/admin_panel"
            android:title="Admin panel"
            android:icon="@drawable/admin_panel_drawable"/></group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/add_user"
            android:title="Create account"
            android:icon="@drawable/add_user_drawable"/>

        <item android:title="">
        <menu>
        <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="EXIT"
        android:icon="@drawable/exit_drawable"/>
        </menu>
        </item>
</menu>
```

как сделать чтобы отображались пункты в зависимости от того какое значение прописано в firestore "users>permission"
при значение 1 только первые 3 пункта. при значение 2 остальные пункты кроме админ меню и создание панели, при значение 999 абсолютно все пункты